# Clicking on soft home button in navigation bar also triggers underlying click listener for a view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

Some newer Android devices have removed the hard Home Button and replaced it with a soft pop up navigation bar at the bottom of the screen that appears when the user swipes up. I've found that the Home Button can also be accessed by hard pressing (not just long clicking, kind of like iOS force touch) the area where the Home Button would appear if navigation bar is visible.  This action triggers an onClick event within the current application before navigating to the device home screen. How can I prevent the onClick event within the application?

You can see in the image below how the navigation bar Home Button overlays the app button. Thanks for any help, I feel like i'm missing something really obvious.

[image]